# Extract duplicate entries in 2D array

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code, I could store the contents of text files in the folder named "TestFolder" and the array has two columns one for the text file name and the other for the contents of this text file ..

```
Sub Test()
Dim fso         As Object
Dim arr         As Variant
Dim lst         As Variant
Dim sFol        As String
Dim fld         As String
Dim fn          As String
Dim i           As Long

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFol = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestFolder\"
fld = Chr(34) & sFol & "*.txt" & Chr(34)
lst = Filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c Dir " & fld & " /b /a-d").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")
ReDim arr(1 To UBound(lst) + 1, 1 To 2)

fn = Dir(sFol & "*.txt")

Do While fn <> ""
    i = i + 1
    arr(i, 1) = fn
    arr(i, 2) = fso.OpenTextFile(sFol & fn).ReadAll
    fn = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

I'm now stuck at how to loop though the array to detect the duplicate text files that has the same content and if they are the same content I would like to populate the file names in worksheet

Example of output .. suppose 001.txt and 003.txt and 0051.txt (if those three text files have the same content) then to populate those file names in A1 / B1 / C1
and so on .. each block of files with the same content to be listed in new row
Regards

Comment: It would help if you'd show what the content looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example to check for double as per your requirement.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim files As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim filenames As String
    Dim matchfound As Boolean

    ReDim arr(1 To 6, 1 To 2)
    ReDim files(1 To 6)

    arr(1, 1) = "FileA": arr(1, 2) = "ContentA"
    arr(2, 1) = "FileB": arr(2, 2) = "ContentB"
    arr(3, 1) = "FileC": arr(3, 2) = "ContentC"
    arr(4, 1) = "FileD": arr(4, 2) = "ContentA"
    arr(5, 1) = "FileE": arr(5, 2) = "ContentB"
    arr(6, 1) = "FileF": arr(6, 2) = "ContentA"

    n = 1

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        filenames = arr(i, 1)

        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If i <> j Then
                If arr(i, 2) = arr(j, 2) Then
                    filenames = filenames & ";" & arr(j, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next j

        For j = LBound(files) To UBound(files)
            If InStr(1, files(j), arr(i, 1)) > 0 Then
                matchfound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If matchfound = False Then
            If InStr(1, filenames, ";") > 0 Then _
            files(n) = filenames
            n = n + 1
        End If

        matchfound = False
    Next i

    For i = LBound(files) To UBound(files)
        Debug.Print files(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
FileA;FileD;FileF
FileB;FileE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But as for those results are the same and I just need to refer me in the worksheet which file names have the same content. I mean 1 and 4 is the same as 4 and 1 .. How can I populate to worksheet one instance ..?

Comment: The text files in the same folder so there are no duplicates in file names at all. The duplicates in the content of those text files. May be two file or three or more have the same content so I need to list all those file names in one row ..So each block of files that have the same content would be listed in one row and so on

Comment: I want the file names to be listed in one row for each block of files that have the same content. Example output: B1=001.txt / C1=003.txt / D1=0051.txt as those three files has the same content. And in A1 the content

Comment: I got FileA in the immediate window and I expect to have both the files "FileA" & "FileD" ..as these are the file names that have the same content

Comment: Ok, try it now. I added more data to the array. You should get FileA, FileD and FileF now

Comment: That's perfect now. Thanks a lot. You're rock. One point I am confused about is how to populate to the worksheet .. and what if there are other block of files that have the same content .. Will they be printed too?

Comment: Change "ContentD" to "ContentB" to see what I mean .. Now there will be two blocks of files that have the same content .. three files and two files
What I need is to list the first block of the three files in row 1 and the second block of files (the second two files) in row 2

Comment: Thank you very much. That's awesome now. Best and Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

A quick example of a loop to check for doubles in a 2D array:

```
Dim i As Long, k As Long

'Loop through the 2nd field of an array, these values are the "base" values
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    'Loop through the array again, these values will be checked against the base values for doubles
    For k = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        'Check if the two records are the same (if they're not on the same iteration)
        If i <> k And arr(i, 1) = arr(k, 1) Then
             'Parse record in first field to sheet
             Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "A") = arr(i , 0)
        End If
    Next k
Next i
```